# How to return an array column in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So I want to write a function that performs z-score transformation for each element in an array and the function should return an array of the result. When I perform the transformation to every element in the array using a `for` loop its not a problem.

```
   x1 = np.array([[4,3,12],[1,5,20],[1,2,3],[10,20,40],[7,2,44]])
   mean = np.average(x1)
   std = np.std(x1)

   for i in x1:
       arr1 = ((i-mean)/std)
       print(arr1)

   type(arr1)
```

However when I use a `for` loop for the column 1 of the array I get `float` values.

```
for x in x1[:,1]:
    arr2 = ((i-mean)/std)
    print(arr2)
    
type(arr2)
```

What can I do to make sure `arr2` that is returned is a 1 dimensional array.[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting pictures on SO and rather post the code/data itself here. Thank you.

Comment: did you mean to calculate the mean and average of columns/rows separately? the question is not clear to me. Maybe you can elaborate on it. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the response Ehsan I have posted the code as well. No I just want to retrieve the "transformed" column/rows not calculate the mean of columns and rows separately.

Comment: Does the posted answer solves the issue? if not, could you please provide us with your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a loop to calculate that:

```
(x-x.mean())/x.std()
```

Example:

```
x = np.arange(3*4).reshape(3,4)
#[[ 0  1  2  3]
# [ 4  5  6  7]
# [ 8  9 10 11]]

(x-x.mean())/x.std()
#[[-1.59325501 -1.30357228 -1.01388955 -0.72420682]
# [-0.43452409 -0.14484136  0.14484136  0.43452409]
# [ 0.72420682  1.01388955  1.30357228  1.59325501]]
```

Then you can select any columns/rows you would like:

selecting first column:

```
((x-x.mean())/x.std())[:,0]
#[-1.59325501 -0.43452409  0.72420682]
```

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, I think your code gets me the output I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same structure you presented, this can help you

```
a = np.array([])
for i in x1[:,1]:
    val = ((i-mean)/std)
    a = np.append(a,val)
type(a)
```

Comment: We are working with `numpy`, so looping should be avoided here as much as possible. Another answer illustrates a way to do it.

Comment: This is why I said ‘the same structure’. You’re right